# Move specific data from one cell in a sheet to another cell in another sheet based on coditions

Tags: vlookup

please help!

I have, x7 sheets on one workbook. x6 rooms - room 1-6 on separate sheets, I then have one final sheet, 'Incoming Funds' which has all the incoming funds for each room.
I need to get specific data from a specific cell in the incoming funds sheet to move to a specific cell in a specific room number..does that make sense??

eg. My incoming Funds tab has all the info for every room, so I receive £1000, for 28 days, for room 1, from WMBC. I just need the data from the Number of days column, in this case, 28 to move to a specific cell in Room 1 work sheet.

Sorry if this is unclear, I'm happy to clarify, i think i need to use the IF and VLOOKUP function but i'm getting a little confused.

Many thanks in advance, Matt

Tried VLOOKUP and IF but i got lost!!